# Server-side Blazor login page path not found after publish

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a cshtml page that manages the login.
When I run the application from Visual Studio the login page works.
But after I publish it I get "Page not found Sorry, but there's nothing here!".

The url differs. When running from the IIS the url is http://localhost/bbs and of course when I run it from VS it's http://localhost:44022.
I have added `<base href="/bbs/" />` and `app.UsePathBase("/bbs");` and the startpage looks correct. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the code being obfuscated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you tell me how you fixed it?

Comment: If I remember correctly. In the end after I pulished I changed the path in the css to the correct path.

Comment: Looking at the project now I have a variable in my SCSS where I add or remove the path depending on if I am publishing or working with development.

Comment: In my case this was not the issue. Maybe some update at the Identity Server because i deleted the scaffolded items and it worked. So I then rescaffolded them and just changed what i needed....